# Using ifeq in makefile to compile either C or CPP file

Tags: c++, makefile, emscripten

I want to compile all the files located in `src/` directory to `bc/%.bc`.
Because I use the `std=c++17` flags which can not be used with `.c` files, I tried this :

```
bc/%.bc: src/%.*
    ifeq '$(suffix $^)' '.c'
        emcc $^ -o $@
    else
        em++ $^ -o $@ -std=c++17
    endif
```

But it does not work, the condition `ifeq` is always false (same when I replace `'.c'` with `'.cpp'`).

Is there a way to achieve a separate compilation based on file suffix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it. The best is probably to separate the rule into two rules, one for `.c` and one for `.cpp`:

```
bc/%.bc: src/%.c
    emcc $< -o $@

bc/%.bc: src/%.cpp
    em++ $^ -o $@ -std=c++17
```

Then you need a way to construct a list of the files you want. (You need this anyway, since that `src/%.*` doesn't work the way you think.)

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard src/%.*)
TARTGETS := $(patsubst src/%, bc/%.bc, $(basename $(SRC_FILES)))
```

And a default rule to build everything:

```
$(TARGETS):
```